# Element is not interactable while filling a google form with selenium

Tags: html, selenium, automation

I'm trying to automate filling a google form but I'm having an issue to select an answer for a drop down menu. The class of the element is not "select" so I can't use selenium "easy way" to select the value I want. This is my script :

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd-GczApKBubTy7ka1ut60waFEdXywuL0dGFQAAZS6_uZKTWQ/viewform"

browser = set_up_driver() # simple browser set up
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
time.sleep(3)

box_xpath = "/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]"
browser.find_element_by_xpath(box_xpath).click()
xpath = """//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/span"""
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

The XPath are correct but this is the error returned when trying to click on the element in the menu :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)
```

I'm pretty sure that this is not an error caused by the element not being loaded
I'm opened to any ways to click on the element that could be used in a thread. I'm currently using pyautogui to use the DOWN key to go down in the dropdown menu but this solution cannot be used in separate threads. Here is a test google from i'm using to test the script on a dropdown menu : https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd-GczApKBubTy7ka1ut60waFEdXywuL0dGFQAAZS6_uZKTWQ/viewform

Comment: Did you try to use expected conditions, google it and set, you should not have issues after

Comment: yes i already tried that and it always go to the timeout and then raises an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


box_xpath = '//div[@role="option" and @data-value]/span'
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, box_xpath))).click()
xpath = '(//div[@role="option" and @data-value]/span)[2]'
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
```

don't use absolute xpath , use relative xpath , also the xpath you used for options was pointing to an element which is not the actual options. change the index from [2] to [3] and so on to find different options

Comment: Working perfectly thank you, could you explain the process of what you did to get the xpath of the element ?  I hae always been using the console in my browser to right click the element and then get the xpath but it looks like it is not the best way to do it

Comment: It is the best way to do it , don't do copy full xpath , use copy custom xpath or make custom xpath urself and check it . Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign